# Temporary Restore of Salesforce

Tags: data-export, database

I always get asked the question by my clients - "What happens if we can't access Salesforce?".

"Take regular backups" we say. But is that enough? Has anyone attempted to restore their Salesforce backup data to a state where they could read it, and possibly even write to it with the proviso that modified or new records are flagged so that they can be restored into Salesforce when it is back up.

I think something like this would take about a day of effort to set up for key information such as Accounts, Contacts and Cases.

Tools like DBAmp are out of the question, because they are a bit too exy for your average client http://www.forceamp.com/, and I would not suggest it unless they were big enough to have a SQL Server instance and an in-house IT team (which if they did, the chances are they are not going to be using Salesforce).

There are tools that will take the attachments and re-name them. http://www.x2od.com/2010/02/08/docs-and-attachs-out-of-salesforce

The data is in CSV and could easily be imported into Access (don't laugh!), some simple Joins created between the data, and a couple of standard one-click forms created so the clients can view the data. Then a quick bit of VBA code to do some auditing of which IDs have changed, and voila - a basic system up and running.

What do you think? Am I being overly optimistic? How would you approach this?

Comment: Are you talking about "what happens if we forget to pay the bill?" or "what do we do when we have no Internet and we have to use local data?" Those are different scenarios, to be certain.

Comment: My answer to this is along the lines of "Consider the customers featured on http://www.salesforce.com/customers/, if SFDC goes down, their applied pressure will ensure that SFDC comes back up and pronto.  Furthermore, past SFDC history is pretty good when it comes to near continuous PROD uptime."  That said, I would not look forward to rebuilding a SFDC app w/ data in another technology especially with lots of custom objects, workflows, and third party system integrations.

Comment: It's not about the how or why Salesforce goes down that is the issue, I am asking "what if". Different organisation's tolerance for what constitutes a point where they need to either restore from a backup or look at their backup data, is different. I would really not look forward to rebuilding into a custom solution either, but it is more around answering the question of "we take these backups, but what do we do with these backups when we need to actually restore something". Does that help clarify?